# How to get the projects having a particular nuget package as reference

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I have around 100 projects in my .NET solution. I managed to get all the nuget packages used in the projects through Package manager console using a simple command.

I have around 100 Nuget packages . Now for every nuget package I want the projects that are having it as a reference. 
i.e Suppose I have three projects A,B and C and I have Nuget package suppose nHibernate.

Manually when I go to references section of each project I see nHibernate is referenced in Project A and Project B. So my dependent project for that package is A and B.

Like this I want for all my nuget packages. How can I do this without any manual task. Like is there any command or way I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a number of options you may have:

1. Search through all the `packages.config` using search in files
2. Write a small console app that loops through all the files and add them in a `MultiValueDictionary` with the package as the key and the values the projects that has that package.
3. There is an node package that can output the packages used [available here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuget-tree).
4. There is a Nuget Package visualizer on github [available here](https://github.com/ThomasArdal/NuGetPackageVisualizer).

Going with option 2 gives you the most flexibility if you/your team has the time to write it. This may be useful in a build pipeline to check for dependencies and alert if there are inconsistencies, for example.

Comment: Thanks @Mihail. As suggested I went with the option 2. Wrote a small console program to get the desired output.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Visual Studio Enterprise you will have Microsoft Architecture Diagrams and Analysis Tools installed.

1. From the top menu bar select `Architecture` then select `Generate Code Map For Solution`

[image]

2. Expand the `Externals`

[image]

3. From the externals list select your package and right click it and select `New Graph From Selection`

[image]

4. A new graph will open. Right click again on the package and select `Show Assemblies Referencing This`

[image]

5. You will get a code graph showing assemblies referencing the package. You can now save this code graph in a separate folder with the packages name for later use.

[image]

You can also do this for multiple packages to view all the dependencies of all packages you selected. On step 3 just select multiple packages with CTRL pressed and follow the same steps.

Comment: If you don't have this option, launch "Visual Studio Installer" than add the Individual Components of 'Code Map' and 'Live Dependency Validation'